# OpenFeign: how to set header without passing it as a param

Tags: java, client, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am trying to implement OpenFeign client.
In my api interface, I have:

```
@RequestLine("GET /testUser/{uuid}") TestUser get(@Param("uuid") UUID uuid);
```

And in my test case, I test it like this:

```
TestUser testUser = TestUserApi.get(uuid);
```

I do not want to pass authorization as a header in api definition, but I want to set it in my test case.
So, do we have any thing like `TestUserApi.setHeader("something", "something")?`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a `RequestInterceptor` to modify the headers before the requests are sent.  You can find more information on how to create and register a `RequestInterceptor` in the [Feign Documentation](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#request-interceptors)